# How to get other columns with are not in GROUP BY clause in Oracle 10g?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, oracle10g

I'm typing a SELECT statement to retrieve information of first time that every client appeared in sales receipts historial, I have a the following statement that retrieve information about client_id and sales_receipt date but I need sales_receipt_id for each receipts. Can you help me? Thanks!

I'm using Oracle Database 10G connected in Toad for Oracle 9.7.2.5.

```
SELECT cli_codigo AS client_id, MIN(cmp_fecha_contable) AS sales_receipt_date
FROM   comprobantes
WHERE  cli_codigo IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cli_codigo
ORDER BY cli_codigo ASC;
```

This statement actually us running well but I need receipt_id too. (All the columns are in the same table named "comprobantes".

I expect the output:

```
RECEIPT_ID  CLIENT_ID   RECEIPT_DATE    
201203000174    061     3/19/2012    
201203000027    118     3/19/2012    
201203000028    166     3/19/2012    
201203000029    139     3/19/2012    
201203000031    055     3/19/2012
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. And take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `keep`:

```
SELECT cli_codigo AS client_id,
       MIN(cmp_fecha_contable) AS sales_receipt_date,
       MIN(receipt_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY cmp_fecha_contable) as first_receipt_id
FROM comprobantes
WHERE cli_codigo IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cli_codigo
ORDER BY cli_codigo ASC;
```

This is essentially an aggregate `first_value()` function.  Although the syntax is a little clunky, `keep` is a very powerful construct in aggregation queries.

Comment: Thanks for help me! It works fine, I will read about "keep" function!

Answer (score 0):

```
select comprobantes.* 
from comprobantes 
left join 
(
SELECT cli_codigo AS client_id, MIN(cmp_fecha_contable) AS sales_receipt_date
FROM   comprobantes
WHERE  cli_codigo IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cli_codigo
ORDER BY cli_codigo ASC
) a on a.client_id = comprobantes.cli_codigo and comprobantes.cmp_fecha_contable = a.sales_receipt_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Column must  beor in group by or in aggregation function.
So you can do:

```
SELECT cli_codigo AS client_id, MIN(cmp_fecha_contable) AS sales_receipt_date, min(RECEIPT_ID) 
FROM   comprobantes
WHERE  cli_codigo IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cli_codigo
ORDER BY cli_codigo ASC
```

Or

```
SELECT cli_codigo AS client_id, MIN(cmp_fecha_contable) AS sales_receipt_date, RECEIPT_ID
FROM   comprobantes
WHERE  cli_codigo IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cli_codigo, RECEIPT_ID
ORDER BY cli_codigo ASC;
```